# Mimicking cart functionality with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am building a store manager application in express that requires me to have three models, users, products and sales. I want to implement the cart functionality for the sales model so I have something like this:

```
const carts = [
   // Cart 1
   {
    {
    Product: Product1 
    Quantity: 20 
    Unit Price: 500 
    Amount: 10000
   },
   {
    Product: product2 
    Quantity: 5 
    Unit Price: 15000 
    Amount: 75000
   },
    {
    Product: anotherProduct 
    Quantity: 10 
    Unit Price: 500 
    Amount: 5000
    },
    {
    Product: Product3 
    Quantity: 2 
    Unit Price: 500 
    Amount: 1000
   },
   Total : 91000
  },

  // Cart 2
  {
   {
    Product: product1 
    Quantity: 20 
    Unit Price: 500 
    Amount: 10000
   },
   {
    Product: product2 
    Quantity: 5 
    Unit Price: 15000 
    Amount: 75000
   },
   Total: 80000
  }
 ];
```

Cart 1 represents a sale by a single attendant while Cart 2 represents a sale by another attendant. How do I include the saleId, attendantId and total for easy referencing?
N.B I will want to run a search/loop through the sales model to filter by saleId

Comment: I think the title is misleading. You are trying to add data or wrap some existing data... ? Are you not in control of the code? The const sales[]; really is const carts[]. Because its a list of carts. So the question you are asking is you want to add to each cart a sale id and attendant id; what is stopping you from doing this?

Comment: @Mr00Anderson How do I add those keys (attendantId and saleId) to the cart for easy referencing? For example if attendant with id of 1 made the sales in cart 1, where exactly do I put that?

Comment: Side note, const means constant, meaning it does not change. Bad idea to declare a cart as const.